# Removing tags using Jsoup library

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jsoup

I need to remove unwanted tags..can any one guide me how to work on it..here is my code

```
public class Test {

    static String val = "<div class=vcard><div class=label>Category: </div><span class=category><a title=Chemicals Manufacturers href=http://www.gmdu.net/list-5-p1.html>Chemicals</a>- <a title=Textile Chemicals Manufacturers href=http://www.gmdu.net/list-5-273-p1.html>Textile Chemicals</a></span><br/><div class=label>Region: </div><span class=adr country-name><a title=Sri Lanka Manufacturers href=http://www.gmdu.net/loca-35-p1.html>Sri Lanka</a></span><span class=fn org>Haycolour (Pvt) Ltd</span><br/></div>";

    public static void main(String a[]) throws IOException
    {
         Document doc = Jsoup.parse(val);
            Elements labels = doc.select("div.vcard div.label");
            for (Element label : labels) {
                System.out.println(String.format("%s:%s", label.text().trim(),label.nextSibling().outerHtml()));
            }
    }
}
```

My Output:

```
Category::<span class="category"><a title="Chemicals" manufacturers="" href="http://www.gmdu.net/list-5-p1.html">Chemicals</a>- <a title="Textile" chemicals="" manufacturers="" href="http://www.gmdu.net/list-5-273-p1.html">Textile Chemicals</a></span>
Region::<span class="adr" country-name=""><a title="Sri" lanka="" manufacturers="" href="http://www.gmdu.net/loca-35-p1.html">Sri Lanka</a></span>
```

Expected output:

```
Category:Chemicals - Textile Chemicals
Region:Sri Lanka Haycolour (Pvt) Ltd
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this easiest to do with jSoup's [nextElementSibling](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#nextElementSibling%28%29)

I replaced your println statement with this:

```
System.out.println(String.format("%s:%s %s", label.text().trim(),label.nextElementSibling().text().trim(),
label.nextElementSibling().nextElementSibling().text().trim()));
```

Produced this output:

```
Category::Chemicals- Textile Chemicals 
Region::Sri Lanka Haycolour (Pvt) Ltd
```

Comment: MagicMan:if chemicals - text Chemicals are dynamic ..how to check whether next sibling exists..can u guide me

Comment: @Giridharan Not sure what you mean by dynamic, but you can always check if the nextElementSibling() is null: `if (label.nextElementSibling() != null) {//do work}`

Comment: Magicman:can u help me to get output of this..am working on this issue.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20975965/jsoup-parsing-parsing-dynamic-values-as-key-value-pair

Comment: @Giridharan Can you mark this as correct? If not what else is still unanswered in this question?